# (iPad related) Horizontal navigation (jquery animation, scroll) not working on iPad

Tags: jquery, ipad, scroll

INTRO: I need debugging help from somebody with an iPad. It's only been tested at an apple store, and I have no access to one myself. If you don't have an iPad to try this with, you might just want to skip the wall of text.

---

The guy I'm designing a horizontal website for somebody who I signed a non-disclosure agreement for.

He needs the website to work on the iPad, as well as all modern browsers, and iPhone. I have all other devices supported and even have a seperate version for mobile devices.

However, one issue remains. The iPad horizontal scrolling is broken. I have not tested this, but he did when he went to the apple store. Here is what he says (from memory):

"The horizontal navigation works when i first click on it, but when it stops scrolling I can't click on the links, they don't even change color. If I scroll the page manually then it fixes and I can click a link, but it only scrolls by a few pixels."

If somebody who owns an iPad can help me out, that would be faaaantastic!

I copied the website over here, stripped out the PHP and anonymized it. There could possibly still be some identifiable information in the code, so just please don't look for it ;) Not that it matters, really.

http://radleygh.com/files/test/

Don't worry about any errors to missing information, that's surely from my stripping everything identifiable out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in my test, what happens is that the upper menu bar scrolls together with the rest of the page, so once you swipe to the right, it gets out of sight; in Safari on MacOS, the menu bar remains at the same relative position within the displayed area when you scroll.

As to the rest, swiping left and right works. The only problem seems to lie with the menu bar also scrolling to the left out of sight.

Hope this helps.